# How can I modify a .PDF file so that it can be copied out of an online & offline e-books App?

Tags: java, pdf, ebook-reader

Adobe PageMaker 7.0 is used to upload a publication(books) into an online - offline e-books App and because it is converted to PDF in order to maintain the page dimensions and the books style, the file does not allow copy in the App.
And it needs really to be copied by the end users.
So, please what line(s) of code can achieve the modifications using Java?

And  can I achieve reference link to the pages cited in the books? So that when I click on any reference text in the pdf, it will link to the page that is referred to?

Answer (score 0):

To convert pdf in java is not that easy you might think. I suggest you to look at adobes website. Otherwise you can look after converters, that do that for you.

Comment: Is there anything itext library that can be of help?

Comment: I guess this article can help you https://viveksb007.wordpress.com/2018/08/13/using-itext-to-edit-pdf-in-android/

Comment: I will see how to utilize it.